# Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am using a PHP script to take the following string date:

```
"Wednesday, 6 March, 2013"
```

I want to format it into a MySQL `date` so that it can then be inserted into the MySQL database.

I am getting the error below.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in 
C:\easyphp\www\twinfocus\submitcalendaritem.php on line 13
```

PHP Script:

```
if (isset($_POST['weddingdate'])){
    $weddingdate = $_POST['weddingdate'];
}
else {
    $weddingdate = '';
}

$date = Date::createFromFormat("D F d, Y", $weddingdate);
$processedweddingdate = $date->format("Y-m-d");

echo $processedweddingdate;
```

I am not sure what's going on.  What does this error mean?

Comment: `createFromFormat` will return false if it didn't manage to make `DateTime` object, so you should check it

Comment: How is it a duplicate when its a different error message ?, using that logic any error what so every could be a duplicate !

Comment: The method `createFromFormat` failed because it could not create a Date.  It gave you 'false' and you ignored that signal.  Applying the method 'format' against a boolean will cause the mentioned error.  Maybe try adding a comma after `D`.  Your date input has two commas.  Then read the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Answer (score 0):

```
"Wednesday, 6 March, 2013"

"D F d, Y"
```

How do these to fit together?

Please read the description of the format parameters in the manual.